# Why would my asp.net-mvc site using nhibernate simply stop doing updates and deletes?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ninject

I have a very simple CRUD asp.net-mvc site that uses nhibernate to interface with a mySQL db.  I am using the UnitOfWork and Repository patterns.  After upgrading to MVC 4 and the latest nhibernate and mySQL versions (via nuget) I am suddenly seeing a weird issue where updates and deletes have stopped working.

Here is an example Delete code in my controller that stopped working:

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        MyEvent c = _eventRepository.FindBy(id);

        _unitOfWork.Begin();
        _eventRepository.Delete(c);
        _unitOfWork.End();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

where the UnitOfWork code looks like this:

```
    public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
    }

   public void End()
    {
        Commit();
        if (Session.IsOpen)
        {
            Session.Close();
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (!_transaction.IsActive)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No active transation");
        }
        _transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }
```

I tested adding a new item that worked fine (new row shows up in DB table) but when I test either Updates or Deletes, the code runs fine (I don't get any exceptions in the code) but the fields aren't being updated when i do an Update and the record isn't deleted when I run the delete code.

So to recap,  reading data from mySQL db works fine,  doing adds works fine but updates and deletes have stopped working for all tables (which did work before).  I did a test doing regular SQL using Toad for MySQL and that worked fine (using the same login credentials that i am using to connect in my code)

To help debug a bit more, I started up nhibernate profiler and this is what i see for a delete or update entry:

[image]

and this is what i see loading a regular read page:

[image]

not sure if that is helpful in explaining the issue but i figured it couldn't hurt to add the screenshots.

Any suggestions on what could be happening.  Could this be an entitlement issue (versus some software library bug?).  Again, as mentioned above this code previously definitely worked.

Here is my Ninject Ioc Code:

```
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString;

        var helper = new NHibernateHelper(connectionString);
        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(helper.SessionFactory)
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();

        var sessionProvider = new SessionProvider();
        Bind<ISession>().ToProvider(sessionProvider);

        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(helper.SessionFactory);

        Bind(typeof(IIntKeyedRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
    }
```

and here is my unitofwork.cs code:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private ITransaction _transaction;

    public ISession Session { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
    }

    public void End()
    {
        Commit();
        if (Session.IsOpen)
        {
            Session.Close();
        }
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Session.IsOpen)
        {
            Session.Close();
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (!_transaction.IsActive)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No active transation");
        }
        _transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (_transaction.IsActive)
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my repository code:

```
public class Repository<T> : IIntKeyedRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private ITransaction _trans;

    public T FindBy(int id)
    {
        return _session.Get<T>(id);
    }

    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public bool Add(T entity)
    {
        _session.Save(entity);
        return true;
    }

    public bool Add(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            _session.Save(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Update(T entity)
    {
        _session.Update(entity);
        return true;
    }

    public bool Delete(T entity)
    {
        _session.Delete(entity);
        return true;
    }

    public bool Delete(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        foreach (T entity in entities)
        {
            _session.Delete(entity);
        }
        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IIntKeyedRepository<T> Members

    public T FindBy(int id)
    {
        return _session.Get<T>(id);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IReadOnlyRepository<T> Members

    public IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        return _session.Query<T>();
    }

    public T FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return FilterBy(expression).Single();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FilterBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return All().Where(expression).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using database generated identifiers? What was the previous NHibernate version? Are you changing the default flush mode?

Comment: I added the code to the question that shows the flushmode.  To be honest, I am not sure what the previous version of nhibernate was but it was using fluent-nhibernate 1.2 so it wasn't that long ago

Comment: @OskarBerggren - just for the record, changing the flushmode to always or commit didn't make any different.

Comment: are you familiar with log4net? you should enable log4net for nhibernate (write to a file) so you can help solve this. https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringLog4netForUseWithNHibernate?_sscc=t

Comment: Are you certain that the _eventRepository returns an object?  I'd expect to see the 'SELECT' statement in the profiler screen shot, even if the delete isn't.

Comment: if i debug i do see an object come back eventRepository.  if it didn't the delete would throw an exception because it would be trying to delete a NULL object

Comment: @leora: What happens if you call `Session.Flush()`?

Comment: @sl3dg3 - adding session.Flush doesn't make any difference

Comment: @leora, may be problem is in call _rep.FindBy(...) which is not from the same session that .Delete(...) is?

Comment: can you pastebin.com yor FindBy and unitofwork class code?

Comment: @Aleksey - this wouldn't explain why it worked in aspnet-mvc 3 and older version of nhibernate and mysql.data

Comment: @leora: You should probably still check. If the session object being used by eventRepository isn't the same session object created in your UnitOfWork class, then you're calling delete on a different session than the one you're trying to commit to. Nothing would happen.

Comment: i put GetHashcode() of the session object in UnitOfWOrk as well as the repostiory and i do get 2 different values

Comment: @Aleksey - i have pasted in my unitofwork and findby code, please have a look and let me know if you see any issues

Comment: @leora so as I understand these procedures should have the same session as partially described at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application so try to organize passing uof in repository or create complex delete method in it

Comment: @leora http://pastebin.com/7fpCheQj if it works, than you can recombine the code to use unitofwork later, else something else is wrong

Comment: @Aleksey - thanks . . this code taht you put in pastebin works so the session must not be matching between repository and unitofwork. ..  still can't figure out why but atleast i know the issue now

Comment: @leora if you do not want to create depency between repository and unitofwork you can go in to ways: send unitofwork instance to repository constructor or create complex FindByIdAndRemove where you can execute two functions and I think the second way is right because sence of unitofwork pattern is to encapsulate database requests into one business action, removebyid, for example

Comment: @Aleksey - ok can you reply as an answer (instead of a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code includes Find and Delete functions calls in scope of a single session. As I think, problem in code from question is using different ones.

```
public T RemoveById(int id)
{
    _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    T res=_session.Get<T>(id);
    _session.Delete(entity);
    _transaction.Commit(); 
}
```

(call from action:)

```
RemoveById<MyEvent>(id)
```

Comment: thanks . . now i am just looking for how i can use unitofwork that isn't coupled with Repository but still shares session object.  Given that I have given you the bounty (as my immediate problem is fixed) but left the question not accepted to still try to get to the bottom of what is wrong in my IOC code

Comment: @leora http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649911/what-is-the-right-way-to-ensure-your-repository-and-unitofwork-class-share-the-s  Robin van der Knaap's answer is what you need I think:3